# Adding hexadecimal numbers with a truncated result

Tags: java, hex

I need help in java regarding memory location addition.

If current memory location is at `fffffff8` and there is an offset of `+10`, in java i would get the value of `100000008` however if i want the value to be `0000 0000 0000 0008` instead of `0000 0001 0000 0008`, how should i go about doing it and is my current code that is doing this calculation optimized?

Currently the code i am using is as followed:

```
long a = Long.parseLong("fffffff8",16) + Long.parseLong("10",16);
String x = Long.toHexString(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears you want to do 32-bit math, why are you using `long` in the first place?

If you just use `int`, you get what you want:

```
int a = 0xfffffff8 + 0x10;
```

will give you `8`.

And as Thomas said, unless you're being handed strings from somwhere there is no need to use `Long.parseLong()` or `Integer.parseInt()` since you can write numeric literals directly in hex form.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to mess with memory locations manually in java, but if you need to truncate the long this should work for you.  Also, unless you're accepting the longs from user input/networking that sends it as a string, 0x#### works instead of parseLong.

```
long a = 0xfffffff8L + 0x10L;
long b = a & 0xffffffffL;
```

Edit: left off my L's on the ends of the constants.